# Discretionary hyphens don't work in paragraphed footnotes, bug?

Tags: footnotes, hyphenation, discretionary

I am getting the impression that discretionary hyphens don't work at all in paragraphed footnotes, not really depending on which package is used for the footnotes. I've painfully experienced it with `manyfoot` and `eledmac`, being many times forced to use `\discretionary` to get proper hyphenation. I was able to reproduce a similar problem with `bigfoot`, the following now is an example with footmisc, which I understand to be the most basic way to make paragraphed footnotes (correct me if I'm wrong.):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[para]{footmisc}
\begin{document}
\footnote{XXXXXXXXXXXXXX just a few normal words to fill up the line
  up to my word hy\-phe\-na\-te\-me}
\end{document}
```

This example will print `hy\-phe\-na\-te\-me` on the second line of the footnote. Gradually removing the `X`es eventually my word will be printed fully at the end of the first footnote line, but never be hyphenated.

I am using `xelatex`. I need the `fontspec` package to display letters with diacritics. For this example, in which I've not used any diacritics, when I comment out fontspec, the word gets hyphenated. Also if I don't use the [para] option of footmisc, or comment out footmisc altogether, the word gets hyphenated.

As I mentioned, I also have many real life examples with other packages.

Comment: I do not use XeLaTeX, but if you add `\usepackage{microtype}` and compile it with LuaLaTeX it works as you want ... Is LuaLaTeX an option for you?

Comment: It really out not look 'quite different'. While it wouldn't be guaranteed to produce identical output, significant differences sounds odd.

Comment: Note that the following will hyphenate: `\footnote{XXXXXXXXXXXXXX just a few normal words to fill up the line  up to my word hy\-phe\-na\-te\-me as}`.

Comment: @jon But do you see _how_ it hyphen-ates it? I had the discretionary hyphen before the `n`.

Comment: @cfr One thing I notice is that in the footnotes the italics font is smaller than the regular font, which looks really odd. My font setup surely would need some adjustment. Anyway, for this book I'm not switching engines anymore, too late.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I compiled last with `lualatex` and didn't notice the difference. However, this seems to work: `\hyphenation{hy-phe-na-te-me}` (goes in the preamble; spell the word normally in the text).

Comment: @jon That's another possible workaround. I've "solved" it for the moment using \discretionary{hyphe-}{nate}{hyphenate} where I needed it, but it's a headache. `\-` should just work, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but `\hyphenation{}` is not a workaround: it is the preferred method for globally setting the correct hyphenation points for words TeX fails to do correctly. According to *TeX By Topic*, the command defines 'hyphenation exceptions for the current value of \language'. Using `\-` is *ad hoc* and therefore discouraged.

Comment: As @jon says. Or dropping `fontspec` also resolves it.

Comment: looks like a xetex feature, probably worth pinging their support list.

Comment: `\hyphenation{..}` and standard hyphenation doesn't work me for with xelatex, pdflatex and lualatex. A direct `\-` works for pdflatex and lualatex but not with xelatex when "native" fonts (with fontspec) are used. Imho the source is the same problem that makes `\showhyphens` fails with native fonts (http://tug.org/pipermail/xetex/2006-September/005176.html). The discretionaries are lost during the boxing and unboxing done by the para option.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would that then be an issue of the packages concerned (`footmisc`, `manyfoot`, `bigfoot`, `(re-/e-)ledmac` and possible others) or of `xelatex`, `pdflatex` `lualatex`?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For me `\hyphenation{}` seemed to work with `xelatex`, at least in the one instance I tried it out on since getting pointed to it yesterday.

Comment: with tex live 2016, this fails to hyphenate if there is no other text on the page wth the footnote call.  however, if some ordinary text is inserted, the footnote is hyphenated using the discretionaries.  however, the discretionaries *are* needed.  in the log, this notice appears: "LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 2746."  (that's line 2746 of `fontspec-xetex.sty` in my test.)